# Android HttpUrlConnection network code affected by mobile network provider

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-volley, httpurlconnection

I suspect that my mobile network provider is affecting the way my code works on my device.

Initially, I wrote google volley code to send a profile image to the server with details about the image owner.

This code had been working seamlessly for a long time, till I ran it on an LG Optimus G Pro and found that it fails quietly for large images. No exception or error. It works well for small images (about 94KB and less)

I tested the code on a Samsung Galaxy S5 and it worked well for large and little images. Then I began to suspect the volley code for no just reason in this case it would seem.

So I ported the code to HttpUrlConnection and used the class `HttpUploader` that I created below.

To my horror, I got exactly the same results as in volley.

However, I now noticed that when it fails, the server still returns a response code of `200` and the loop writing the image bytes still completes.

The next suspect then was the network provider, say **ETS**

I connected the offending device to the wireless hotspot of the Galaxy S5 using MTN Nigeria and this time, the code worked.

I now connected the Galaxy S5 to the wireless hotspot of the LG Optimus Pro using **ETS** and lo and behold, the same issue happened to the Galaxy S5.

So I confirmed my suspicions that the **ETS** network was bugging the code.

Here is the HttpUrlConnection code:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by hp on 1/18/2016.
 */
public abstract class HttpUploader {

    /**
     * This is important for uploading multipart data containing a large file.
     * @param serverUrl The server url
     * @param f The file to be uploaded
     * @param params The parameters of text data to be uploaded
     * @param values The values of text  data to be uploaded
     * @return the server's response
     */
    public void uploadStuff(final String serverUrl,final int retries,final File f,final String[]params,final String...values){
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
onPreStart();

        if( params==null || values==null || serverUrl==null || params.length!=values.length){
            return;
        }
        String response = "error";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;

        String urlServer = serverUrl;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( f );

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);
            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            for(int i=0;i<params.length;i++){
                String param = params[i];
                String value = values[i];

                String token = "token-"+i;
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+param+"\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + token.length() + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(value + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            }//end or loop


            String connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""
                    + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\"" + lineEnd;

            outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            try {
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Utils.logErrorMessage("outofmemoryerror");
                        response = "outofmemoryerror";
                    }
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "error";
                Utils.logErrorMessage("exception: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();


            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                response = "true";
            }
            else{

             if(retries!=0) {
                 uploadStuff(serverUrl, retries - 1, f, params, values);
             }
                  response = "false";
            }

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();

            //for android InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            java.io.InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            int ch;
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){
                b.append( (char)ch );
            }

            String responseString = b.toString();
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                onSuccess(responseString);
            }
            else{
                onError(responseString);
            }
            Utils.logErrorMessage("response string is " + responseString); //Here is the actual output

            outputStream.close();
            outputStream = null;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception handling
            response = "error";

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


       }
   }).start();
    }





    public abstract void onPreStart();
    public abstract void onSuccess(String response);

    public abstract void onError(String response);


}
```

I usually call it like this:

```
        new HttpUploader() {
            @Override
            public void onPreStart() {}
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final String response) {}
            @Override
            public void onError(final String response) {}
        }.uploadStuff(url, 5, imageSrc, new String[]{"key", "creator_name", "user_id", "user_phone"}, "file", Utils.owner.getFullName(), Utils.owner.getId(), Utils.owner.getFullPhoneNumber(),
                );
```

Is there any way that I can correct this?

I find it shocking that the HttpUrlConnection exposed that the code finds the server and everything is ok, but it does not upload the image to the server at all.

I used WhatsApp on the offending network and it uploads images of any size. What hack or workaround can I use to save the situation?
Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us the details about your bug? When it fails, when uploading a image?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that at least twice in the question. The code is designed to send a profile image and textual data about the image owner to the server.

Comment: Everything completes normally in the code but it does not seen to get the data across to the server at all

Comment: Do you think this is a network connection problem? Slow connection, time-out, etc. How long before the task completes?

Comment: Hmmm, Maybe I should check that out...though, the offending network has a reputation of being 'faster' than the one that even worked here in Nigeria

Comment: But what do you think? even if the connection is slow, why is it returning a response code of 200? and the image bytes writing loop completes successfully; and then it fails to upload. Are these possible under the circumstances?

Comment: The connection is fast enough and even when I increased the timeout it was still same

Comment: Please I still need an answer to this question.

Comment: *it does not seen to get the data across to the server at all* You mean even plain-text inputs are not passed?

Comment: The code works fine for images from 90 kilobytes or so and less. Only large images fail on that network. Google's volley library also failed on this network. But on other networks, both Volley and this code worked. On the network however, WhatsApp images upload, so I would like to know if there are parameters that can be tweaked to make it work.